# Comparing two arrays to retrieve values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I asked a similar question earlier but it was unclear. I am building an array.  At the moment I am doing this

```
let myArray = [];
const header = ["Category", "Count", { role: 'style' }];
const categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"];
const colors = ["red", "blue", "silver", "yellow"];
myArray.push(header);
categories.forEach((x,i) => {
    myArray.push([x, 0, colors[i]]);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

The output of the above is the following

```
[
    ["Category","Count",{"role":"style"}],
    ["cat1",0,"red"],
    ["cat2",0,"blue"],
    ["cat3",0,"silver"],
    ["cat4",0,"yellow"]
]
```

You can see that the counts are currently manually set to 0.  I then have a second array I retrieve from the server called `dataArray`.  The contents of this are

```
[
    {"Category":"cat3","Count":59},
    {"Category":"cat1","Count":109},
    {"Category":"cat2","Count":120},
    {"Category":"cat4","Count":57}
]
```

What I am trying to do is is with `myArray` I produced above, I need to switch the 0's out with the correct counts found for the Category within `dataArray`.  So essentially `myArray` should end up like this

```
[
    ["Category","Count",{"role":"style"}],
    ["cat1",109,"red"],
    ["cat2",120,"blue"],
    ["cat3",59,"silver"],
    ["cat4",57,"yellow"]
]
```

How would I go about cross comparing the two arrays?

Thanks

Comment: This is exact similar question you asked and I answered. You commented that the output is wrong(This also because of your weak explanation) 2 hours before and now you are asking the same question. Wait for a day or so and then do like this. Better to put it on featured. You need to be patient.

Comment: @maheer no, not really. This question is slightly different. (it asks about merging two tables)

Comment: Just to clear things up for @MaheerAli.  In their defence the questions are very similar.  I thought I worded the initial question incorrectly and as such did not get the desired output.  However, it got me to a point where I could ask the question more clearly which is what I done here.

Comment: To help me better understand things, can you comment if you downvote an answer please.  Just want to see why it may be wrong.

Comment: @kate_hudson I downvote answers if they aren't working or if they are just unexplained code dumps. So did I here ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your server data, create a Map of category to count:

```
  const countOf = new Map();

  for(const { Category, Count } of serverData)
    countOf.set(Category, Count);
```

Then you can go over your table, look up the count and replace it:

```
 const Count = 1, Category = 0;

 for(const row of table.slice(1))
   row[Count] = countOf.get(row[Category]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick'n'dirty:

```js
let myArray = [];
const header = ["Category", "Count", { role: 'style' }];
const categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"];
const colors = ["red", "blue", "silver", "yellow"];

myArray.push(header);
categories.forEach((x,i) => {
    myArray.push([x, 0, colors[i]]);
});

const dataArray = [
    {"Category":"cat3","Count":59},
    {"Category":"cat1","Count":109},
    {"Category":"cat2","Count":120},
    {"Category":"cat4","Count":57}
];

dataArray.forEach(e => {
    const elementToUpdate = myArray.find(x => x[0] === e.Category);
    elementToUpdate && (elementToUpdate[1] = e.Count);
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you have an array

```
var array1 = [
    ["Category","Count",{"role":"style"}],
    ["cat1",0,"red"],
    ["cat2",0,"blue"],
    ["cat3",0,"silver"],
    ["cat4",0,"yellow"]
]
```

And another array from server

```
var serverarr = [
    {"Category":"cat3","Count":59},
    {"Category":"cat1","Count":109},
    {"Category":"cat2","Count":120},
    {"Category":"cat4","Count":57}
]
```

Now you need to produce

```
[
    ["Category","Count",{"role":"style"}],
    ["cat1",109,"red"],
    ["cat2",120,"blue"],
    ["cat3",59,"silver"],
    ["cat4",57,"yellow"]
]
```

To archive this you need to do

```
serverarr.forEach(item =>{
  array1.forEach(data =>{
    if(data[0] === item.Category){
     data[1] = item.Count; 
    }   
  });
});
```

Now your `array1` will have your desire result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let cat={};
dataArray.forEach(x=> cat[x.Category]=x.Count);
data.forEach((x,i)=> i>0? x[1]=cat[x[0]]:0 );
```

```js
let data= [
    ["Category","Count",{"role":"style"}],
    ["cat1",0,"red"],
    ["cat2",0,"blue"],
    ["cat3",0,"silver"],
    ["cat4",0,"yellow"]
]

let dataArray = [
    {"Category":"cat3","Count":59},
    {"Category":"cat1","Count":109},
    {"Category":"cat2","Count":120},
    {"Category":"cat4","Count":57}
]

let cat={};
dataArray.forEach(x=> cat[x.Category]=x.Count);
data.forEach((x,i)=> i>0? x[1]=cat[x[0]]:0 );

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I had a similar situation, I believe the following would get the results you are looking for. I think it is easy to read as well, although my variable names can be replaced of course.

```
dataArray.forEach((x) => {
    myArray.forEach((z) => {
        if (z.includes(x.Category)) {
            z.splice(z.indexOf('0'), 0, x.Count);
        }
    });
});
```